# html - Adding button gives additional width

Tags: html, css, button

I have a simple div with 2 `<textarea>`s in it. It works fine till here. When I add a button to it, the div expands its width automatically. I don't know why this is happening!

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e48q7/1).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="offer_a_help">
    <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
    <button id="send_offer">Send Offer</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.offer_a_help {
    min-width: 350px;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100%/2 - 350px/2);
    left: calc(100%/2 - 250px/2);
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    text-align: center;
}
.offer_a_help textarea {
    width: 98%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: in your jsfiddle in first version (without button) you have used width in second you have used min-width?

Comment: From your fiddle, I cant tell what is wrong.....when I remove the button it looks exactly the same...http://jsfiddle.net/e48q7/2/

Comment: @KyleK you removed the button, I want the button but when I add it it just expands in width! IDK why? that's what I am asking!

Comment: @Ara thanks it solved my problem, make it a answer i will accept it

Comment: I see the effect but one of your fiddles is slightly different and misleading the viewers.

Comment: @MarcAudet yeah, Ara told me!

Comment: I know you got your answer already. Just thought I should mention this: Your textarea width on the first fiddle is `width: 98%;` and on the second is `width: 100%;`

Comment: @bizzehdee Tags in the title aren't all that big a deal. You can remove them, but you should make other improvements to the post as well. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first fiddle you have used width / height:

[First](http://jsfiddle.net/YE5MP/)

```
width: 350px;
height: 250px;
```

in second you have used min-width / min-height

[Second](http://jsfiddle.net/e48q7/1/)

```
min-width: 350px;
min-height: 250px;
```

compare your codes, use either one on both,

Comment: The question still remains, however, why is the width of the textarea elements changing when you remove the button element?

Comment: @MarcAudet well he asked about width of div, which is solved (not text area), and about your question, width of textarea is a percent (98%) of parent div, so when you remove the button and width of div changes, textarea's width also change